# error 4 in liblept.so.4.0.3 : at leptonica 1.72 install

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, leptonica, intel-galileo

I am using Linux Yocto on a Intel® Galileo development board and I am trying to install Leptonica but when I type `make check` I receive the following error.

> [20695.738252] lt-psioseg_reg[29506]: segfault at 0 ip b7602f1c sp
>   bf9754a0 error 4 in liblept.so.4.0.3[b7590000+250000] FAIL:
>   psioseg_reg

It appears that the error in file "liblept.so.4.0.3" How do I fix this problem?